# Spring declaration by multiple interfaces

Tags: spring, oop, interface

I have some architecture issue. 
I have two different interfaces (`IntefaceA`, `IntefaceB`) and a class (`MyClass`), which implements these.
When I inject `MyClass` like this:

```
@Autowired
InterfaceA myClass;
```

I am not able to use implemented methods from `InterfaceB`.

My idea was to check with the `instanceof MyClass`, to be able to call the method from `InterfaceB`, but currently autowired object as `InterfaceA` is not a (sub)-type from `MyClass`.

```
if(myClass instanceof MyClass) {
                InterfaceB myClassFromInterfaceB =(InterfaceB) myClass;
                result= myClassFromInterfaceB.methodFromInterfaceB
            }
```

How can I autowire **one** object in spring, which can call all methods from all interfaces, which will be implemented by this object?

It is only possible to declare two different objects ?

Comment: Inject MyClass. Or use `instanceof InterfaceB`. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-proxying

Comment: You are using interfaces then program to those interfaces. Just inject them both, they will point to the same instance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If the code may be changed, the cleanest way would be creating an interface that is composed of these two interfaces and making your implementation class derive from it.
Then you can declare your field to inject with this super interface as type :

```
@Autowired
InterfaceAandB myClass;
```

If the code cannot be changed, as alternative declare two fields to autowire in your bean and specify different interface types for each field.
It will result to a same object injected twice but referenced by two variable with different interfaces :

```
@Autowired
InterfaceA myA;

@Autowired
InterfaceB myB;
```

Comment: thx for answer. Common "InterfaceAandB" interface would be my next solution, but from context i dont need such interface, which will be extended by InterfaceA or InterfaceB